# How to find a gdrive file link

Tags: java, google-drive-api, synchronization, gdrive

I have created a folder name "Invoices" in my laptop. And shared as public folder in gDrive.
Now I create invoices using Java Application as save on that file. They are finely syncing with gDrive Invoices" Folder and all are in as public access mode.
Every invoices is uploaded is in public access mode automatically.
But how can I find the link of each file automatically or Any code using Java?

Comment: depending upon the type of file when you do a file.get there should be a WebView link or a download link returned in the response.   Nothing is automatic this is programming you need to make a request.   Do a file.list to get back a list of all the files in the directory.

Comment: Mr. @DaImTo Thank you very much for your comment. Yes I got it  and I only use PDF format.And may I know that are there any  way to request the "link" using JAVA? When I right click on my file there is "Copy link to clipboard" in the menu.

Comment: Mrs. Hasan Dulanga :  Please edit your question and include your code.   I assume you are using the google api java client library?   It should be able to do this no problems.   [Google drive Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/java)

Comment: You may also want to read [The use of gender-specific pronouns on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262119/1841839)

Comment: I didn't try to use any code get link  as I don't know how to start. Ok. I'll read now. And Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to start would be with the Google apis java client library.  This client library will make it easer for you to connect to the api and authorize your aplication.

I recommend starting with the [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/java) it will show you how to create an application and connect to the google drive api.

Just watch the dependencies last time i tried they were out of date make sure to grab the latest

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'DriveQuickstart'
sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.33.0'
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.32.1'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev20211107-1.32.1'
}
```

If you have any issues getting it to work edit your question and include your code i would be happy to have a look i think i have an updated sample floating around.  That i have not published to my own website yet.